# Al modificar una fila de tabla, vuelve al inicio de la tabla

Tags: javascript, html-tabla

Tengo una pagina html con una tabla con varias columnas.
Una de esas columnas es modificable haciendo un clic dentro de una fila, teniendo 2 valores posibles (Pendiente / Validado).
Lo realizo correctamente mediante javascript, el problema es que cuando modifico uno de los ultimas filas, me vuelve siempre al inicio de la tabla, como si recargara la tabla.

Comment: Es muy difícil ayudarte si no compartes al menos los snippets del código en cuestión para revisar que puede estar pasando.

Comment: Te paso el link con la pagina de ejemplo. Puedo modificar la ultima columna , pero luego vuelve al inicio. La idea es cargar lso datos de una base mysql, una vez que esto funcione. https://www.carmelorowing.com.uy/reservas/marco.html

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que tienes un link `<a>` con un atributo `href` cuyo comportamiento por defecto es navegar hacia la ruta que definas en ese atributo. Actualmente su valor es un "`#`" el cual es un símbolo que se usa para referenciar un elemento en la página que contenga un `id` con el identificador que decidas poner seguido del "`#`".

Es decir, en tu página podrías tener un elemento tal que así:

```
<div id="main-container">...</div>
```

Y un link que lo referencie:

```
<a href="#main-container">Inicio</a>
```

Al dar click a este link la página hará scroll hasta ese elemento.
Sin embargo, si no hay un elemento con ese id simplemente hace scroll al principio de la página, lo cual es básicamente lo que te está sucediendo.

Ahora, para evitar que esto ocurra y **solucionar tu problema** simplemente debes llamar el método `preventDefault` del evento `click` de tu link:

```
a = $('a');

// agrega el argumento event dentro del handler:
a.click(function(event) {
  // llama event.preventDefault para prevenir el comportamiento por defecto
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo voy a probar. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias, en este ejemplo funciona. ahora mi problema es mas complejo. Por supuesto que no soy experto en programacion web, hago programacion para PC. Pero tengo un par de clientes que me pidieron hacer unos proyectos web , asi que tuve que meterme. El tema es que para mostra los datos utilizo una tabla con la clase de jquery.datatables.min.js, con paginacion. Al clicar sobre pendiente llamo una pagina php para modificar el estado en la base mysql, y vuelvo al listado. Cuando vuelvo al listado (invocando la pagina listado.php), logicamente me recarga todo de nuevo. Ese es mi problema. No se como clicar en Pendiente, modificar la base , modificar el texto a Validado y quedarme en la posicion. Gracias por tu ayuda